Low resolution color channel into high resolution color channel
There is super resolution enhancement, but it's about image dimension resolution, such as 128×128×3 image can be enhanced into 2048×2048×3 HD image, where the color information is still 24-bit.
But, is there a model that can decode low resolution color channel such as RGB332 like 640×480×1 into common RGB (24-bit), 640×480×3?
